# Response not added to the DOM structure after calling rails helper method render in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm displaying some details that I require to be rendered inside a template once the user clicks on a link like this one -

`<%= link_to "show user", show_user_path(user.id), method: :get, remote: true %>`

My controller looks like this -

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render :partial => "userprofile", :locals => { :user => @user }
end
```

After clicking on the link the request works just fine. I obtain a response of the template code as shown in the Chrome debugging tool's **Network Tab** and there are no errors in the console.

The HTML of the response is not appended to the DOM structure of the page, so I am unable to view the details sent. Please, help me I'm still new to the RoR framework.
Thanks!!!

***Edit - Partial File: userprofile.html.erb***

```
<h1><%= user.name %></h1>
<p><%= user.bio %></p>
```

The fields are complete and no errors were thrown by the server. It returned -

```
Rendered _userprofile.html.erb <3.0ms>
Completed 200 OK in 18ms <Views: 13ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms>
```

Comment: edit answer and post partial file too.

Comment: I've added the partial file @LukyBoy-KU . Please, help me find the solution I do not wish to write explicit ajax requests for the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement events listener, for next AJAX events:

- ajax:beforeSend
- ajax:success
- ajax:complete
- ajax:error

So in result, your js should looks like:

```
$('#show_user_link').bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
  $('body').append(xhr.responseText);
})
```

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work. The ajax request is automatically generated because I used the **link_to** helper. I thought the RoR **render :partial** helper method automatically renders the html template. I'm confused, hope to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change your show method into:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Next, you create new file show.js.erb. Then, you have to determine what div/section do you want to add your render. In this case, I have to

```
$("#users").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "userprofile", :locals => { :user => @user }) %>");
```

This is just example in index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "show user", show_user_path(user.id), method: :get, remote: true %>
<div id="users">
   <!-- will be replaced by partial user_profile !>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!! That worked well. I really wished it could have been done without the show.js.erb, but this looks like a good solution.